# How to set custom fancy pagestyle back to default fancy

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using a custom fancy pagestyle for my acronyms pages and I am wondering how I set the pagestyle back to "default" for the rest of my document. This is my example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, DIV12, BCOR16mm, listof=totoc ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackge{acronym}
\fancypagestyle{acronyms}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{Acronyms}
  \fancyhead[RE]{Acronyms}
  \cfoot{\thepage}
}
\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{acronyms}
\section{Acronyms}
  \begin{acronym}
    \acro{BLA}{BLA}
  \end{acronym}
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{fancy}
\section{Section 2}
Some Text....
\end{document}
```

The effect is that the pagestyle is still set to `\pagestyle{acronyms}` and not set back to "default". 
I also used `\thispagestyle{acronyms}` but since my acronyms are more than one page this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Using `fancyhdr` together with `scrartcl` is no good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with a KOMA-Script class the usage of `scrlayer-scrpage` is recommended:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, DIV=12, BCOR=16mm, listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline,
  markcase=upper
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{acronym}
\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{acronyms}{%
  \ihead{}\ohead{Acronyms}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{acronyms}
\section{Acronyms}
  \begin{acronym}
    \acro{BLA}{BLA}
  \end{acronym}
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

It is also possible to use `fancyhdr`. Then you have to define another page style:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, DIV=12, BCOR=16mm, listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{main}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{acronym}
\fancypagestyle{acronyms}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{Acronyms}
  \cfoot{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{acronyms}
  \section{Acronyms}
  \begin{acronym}
    \acro{BLA}{BLA}
  \end{acronym}
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{main}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

Warning: Do not ignore any warning regarding the old font commands like \rm, \sl. Note that fancyhdr uses this commands in its default header and footer definitions.

Starting with the [current prerelease of the next KOMA-Script Version (3.20)](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801) KOMA Script does not define this old commands, see [Bekannte Probleme und Änderungen in der zukünftigen KOMA-Script-Version](http://www.komascript.de/releasesvn) (German). So

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/11/06]
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

will result in errors. You can avoid the errors if you either use \fancyhf{} and define your own header and footer using \fancyhead and \fancyfoot without the usage of old font commands or you use a compatibility option.